# Show Loader Snaps in GFlags.exe, fails to capture any output in WinDbg

Tags: windbg, gflags

I'm having a customer use Show Loader Snaps in WinDbg to capture output in WinDbg so we can figure out what library is failing to load in our product on their Win7 machine.

Unfortunately all that the Debugger seemed to capture was the command 'go' to WinDbg, and NTTerminateProcess when the process ends.

Am I missing something obvious that would prevent the Loader Snaps from being printed to the Debugger's Command window?

Comment: How is the customer using WinDbg? Are they attaching or launching the process from within WinDbg? In order to view the full output they should launch the .exe from within WinDbg to see the output. Note that the output will be huge so they should write to logfile `.logopen c:\temp\mylog.txt` or from within WinDbg just 'Edit>Write Window Text to File...'

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do this using gflags but here's an example from the debugger doc: `gflags /i notepad.exe +sls`. This will affect all **new** instances of notepad. Maybe the customer mistyped your program's exe name or they didn't start a new instance of your program.